# binding a UDP port and listening for connections

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, udp, minecraft

When I try to ping a Minecraft server via LAN, the [documents](https://wiki.vg/Server_List_Ping#Ping_via_LAN_.28Open_to_LAN_in_Singleplayer.29) say the following:

> In Singeplayer there is a function called "Open to LAN". Minecraft (in the serverlist) binds a UDP port and listens for connections to 224.0.2.60:4445 (Yes, that is the actual IP, no matter in what network you are or what your local IP Address is)"  .......  client side, bind a UDP socket and listen for connections. You can use a MulticastSocket for that.

I tried to implement this in Python in the following way:

```py
import socket

UDP_IP = "224.0.2.60"
UDP_PORT = 4445

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
    print("received message: %s" % data)
```

Which gave me an `OSError: [WinError 10049]` error.

Please help :( I have no idea what's wrong with my code.

By the way, sending packets to that port works, and the fake server shows up on the Minecraft app.

Comment: You need to join the group 224.0.2.60.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot bind to a multicast address like that. It is somewhat more involved.
I recommend to read [this article](https://pymotw.com/2/socket/multicast.html) that explains all the details of using multicast with Python.

Comment: Actually you can, and your own link says so, but only on Linux. But binding is not the whole story.

Comment: @user207421– According to the OP’s error message, it is about Windows, not Linux.

Comment: So that makes your link irrelevant.

Comment: @user207421 – The code on that page is OS-independent and works fine with Windows, too. So the link is relevant.